# Using an External SVG with <use> element

Tags: svg

I faced a weird problem when I was practicing SVG, Using an External SVG with <use> element.

I created a SVG file and named it: circle.svg

```
<!-- circle.svg -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <circle id="my-circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Then created a html file and named it:

```
<!-- use.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SVG Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Using an External SVG</h1>
    <svg width="100" height="100">
        <use xlink:href="circle.svg#my-circle"></use>
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

but when I execute the use.html, the blue circle is not shown.
I checked the Inspect and it showed 100*100 for <svg> element and 0*0 for <use> element.

Need to add, the both files are in the same folder. And, I am using the last version of Chrome. And, tested it in Firefox, Opera, Edge, but the problem was persisting as well.

I checked educational sites like css-tricks.com and they mentioned this example as a working code.

Comment: Either shorten `xlink:href` to `href` (supported in all browsers), or declare the namespace with a `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` attribute.